# Found nil while unwrapping optional value when add object to array

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I defined :

```
var lstQuotations : [Student]!
```

[image: Here is my problem]

I try to create new object of Student and add to list of student. but it always error like that.. thank in advance for your solution.

Comment: Can you print your array to check if it's nil ?

Comment: Make sure your array is initialized before you add elements to it: lstQuotations = [Student]()

Comment: A good example of the abuse of implicit unwrapped optionals.

Comment: student is a simple class or nsObject class?

Comment: opp!!! that it... I really forgot initialize it .. very thank ..

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize your array first

```
var lstQuotations = [Student]()
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as solution. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
    var lstQuotations = [Student]()

    for i in 1...10 {

        let stu = Student()

        stu.id = "\(i)"
        stu.name = "Student {\(i)}"

        lstQuotations.append(stu)
    }
```

And create class like this:

```
class Student {
   var id : String!
   var name : String!
}
```